# Looking for a free Solidity reversing tool (not decompiler)

Tags: solidity, evm

I found there is a Solidity reversing plugin for IDA Pro and Binary Ninja, but it costs a lot for students. Are there any free Solidity plugins? Or are there any other free reversing tools that have a Solidity plugin?

Comment: I think the term you can search for is "decompilers" and this is a duplicate.

Comment: First of all, I am not looking for a 'decompiler.' Looking for a reversing tool that enables tracking between assembly. Reversing tool usually shows how the interaction happens. However, decompiler usually converts bytecode into source code (usually not original source). I was looking for the reversing tool in that context. So, I found IDA pro, binary ninja with solidity plugin, but it costs a lot to students. This is why I was looking for free reversing tool with solidity plugin.

Comment: Sorry you might need to explain better what you are looking for. Binary Ninja website says they're a decompiler `<meta name="description" content="Binary Ninja is a modern reverse engineering platform with a scriptable and extensible decompiler.">`. Let me try help edit and reopen question.

Comment: Maybe a combination of a decompiler and remix.ethereum.org might help you.